# Prove the union $\bigcup A_n$ has empty interior in $X$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Let $X$ be a Hausdorff compact space; let $\{A_n\}$ be a countable collection of closed set of $X$. Show that if each set $A_n$ has empty interior in $X$, then the union $\bigcup A_n$ has empty interior in $X$.

My solution:

Suppose that, $U=$ interior of $\bigcup A_n$ is nonempty. Then any open subset of $U$ can not have isolated point, since then all interior of $A_n$ can not be empty. (If $U$ have isolated point, then for some $x\in X$ with $\{x\}\subset U$ is an open set, then it must be a subset of some $A_n$, since $\{x\}$ do not intersects with $X-A_n$)

Let, $x_0$ and $x_1$ (where $x_1\in A_{1}$) are two points in $U$. Then there exists two disjoint open sets in $X$, say, $B_1$ and $C_1$. Take, $B_2=U\cap A^c_{1}\cap C_1$, then $x_1\notin \bar B_2$.

Since $B_2$ is an open set containing $U$, there is a point $x_2\in B_2$ with $x_2\in A_{k_2}$ for some $k_2$,  for which, in the same way, we can get an open set $C_2$ such that $x_2\notin \bar B_3$ with $B_3=U\cap A^c_{k_2}\cap C_2$

In this way, we can find sequence $\bar B_2\supset \bar B_3\supset\dots$

Since, $X$ is compact, $\bigcap_{n\geq 2} \bar B_n$ is nonempty. Then there exists a point $x$ which is an element of interior of $A_n$, for some $n$. A contradiction.

Is my solution ok?

Comment: You are aware of the fact that this is a particular case of the Baire category theorem, right?

Comment: no @JoséCarlosSantos , it is in chapter 8, I am solving chapter 3. (Although, in the footnote of that problem, that was written)

Comment: I only know compactness, finite intersection property etc (Reading the chapter "Compactness") @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: When you write that “there exists two disjoint open sets in $X$, say, $B_1$ and $C_1$”, what do you mean?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I realised, this solution has a lots of errors, so I re-post it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2505370/show-that-the-union-bigcup-a-n-has-empty-interior-in-x)